# Update denied for 22.04.1 server from official archive servers

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, 22.04

I have *again* a problem getting updates for a server which runs Ubuntu 22.04.1 (only this one). It is a new server (max a week old) and was upgraded from 20.04.5 to 22.04.1 from a fresh installation. From the start there were problems with the updates and I did get a prompt near the end of the installation process because of that. That is also the reason why I tried in the end a 20.04.5 installation, after I had these problems with a fresh 22.04.1 installation. I thought I had it fixed it with clearing some keys (after that it worked until next time I checked), but obviously not. I think there is something wrong with the security keys on this server, but what exactly is beyond me at the moment.

Has someone any idea what is maybe going on? Because I had these problems from the start and my other serves a fine, but also older installations (20.04.5 and 22.04.1 versions).

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64)
```

When I run `sudo apt update`

```
Err:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  403  Forbidden: category denied [IP: 141.30.62.26 80]

Err:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  403  Forbidden: category denied [IP: 185.125.188.12 80]

Reading package lists... Done

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  403  Forbidden: category denied [IP: 141.30.62.26 80]

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  403  Forbidden: category denied [IP: 185.125.188.12 80]
```

I had to cut more information about it, because of the **This looks like spam** message.

### Update

After some time (weeks) it did fix itself, very strange. Maybe it had something to do with the VMware software on the host machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with our network firewall and after the firewall was replaced (because it was to old), the update problem was solved.